# Identifying multiple devices for same build in Android CI automation

Tags: android, jenkins, android-espresso, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on android espresso automation. I have the same build across multiple devices. When i `connectedCheck`, all the available devices will be test against the same test case in espresso.

In the test case, I am testing some features that will send data to my server. I currently have parameter pass in from Jenkins to the espresso  that help me know what build this is. Then during test I append the parameter into data I send to server. In this way I know at my server that there is a data sent from the particular build. However, I am not able to identify each device at the backend, because all the data has the same build number as well as the parameter I append. I am looking for a way to identify these devices and then I will need to pass the identifier back to Jenkins so that I will take them and start downstream component for server verification.

The flow I currently have and need to be improved:

1. Jenkins triggered and pass in param to gradle on remote box.
2. Gradle runs instrumentation test across all devices with same build appended with param from jenkins
3. Once current job is done, I trigger another job with the known identifier. ( this is the step blocked me)
4. Downstream job gets the identifier and do server verification. (Based on this approach, Jenkins does not know each devices identifiers to pass onto this downstream job)

Can anyone address me the best practice of it?